# No error when I run the code, but I keep getting the wrong output, and I can’t tell why

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, cs50, wordle-game

I am writing a program supposed to simulate the once-popular Wordle game. I have written most of the code, and it all appears to work correctly except for the function that checks for the letters in the right or wrong position or not in the word at all. No error message is returned, but the code seems to acknowledge letters that are in the guesses but not in the actual word, and I can’t figure out why. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Here is the code for the function:

```
int check_word(string guess, int wordsize, int status[], string choice)
{
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 0; guess[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < wordsize; j++)
        {
            if (guess[i] == choice[i])
            {
                status[i] = EXACT;
                score += EXACT;
                break;
            }
            else if (guess[i] == choice[j] && status[i] != EXACT)
            {
                status[i] = CLOSE;
                score += CLOSE;
            }
            else if (guess[i] != choice[j] && status[i] != EXACT && status[i] != CLOSE)
            {
                status[i] = WRONG;
                score += WRONG;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

I tried creating a loop to iterate over the characters in guess, and inside that loop, I made another loop to iterate over the actual word to be guessed (choice). It is supposed to check if the current character is in the right spot, and if it is, assign a particular score to the corresponding location in an array I created, if not then it’s supposed to compare the current character to every letter in the actual word, and assign another score if found, if not, then a final score is allocated. It somewhat works, but I noticed that it sometimes acknowledges letters that are in guess but not in the actual word, I.e., choice, and I do not know why.

Comment: Your description, your code, and the [description I found on-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordle) seem to be 3 different things. Not sure how to unravel this.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, so we cannot try to reproduce your problem. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. I suggest to add a `main` function that calls `check_word` with hard-coded data and prints the result. Show the actual and expected output. The `else if (guess[i] != choice[j]...` is probably wrong because it will set or add `WRONG` if any combination of letters does not match. This might influence the score of later `CLOSE` results.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Tc7Poz4bq) is my attempt at a rewrite of the code in your post preserving its current behavior. It is not an attempt at a fix, it is an attempt to make what your current code is (incorrectly) doing clearer. (And I did replace the CS50 `string` with the more conventional equivalent `char *`)

Comment: One thing I missed - is the status array appropriately initialized before being passed to the function? If it could initially contain entries set to EXACT or CLOSE, I haven't properly accounted for that in my rewrite and it could also be one of the bugs in your code.